# Bootstrap Popover not working when code hosted locally, but working on jsbin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

This is insane... I've been trying to figure out why my popover code won't when hosted locally, but working fine on jsbin. Let me know what you guys think, I going crazy over this. Thanks to you all!!

So here it is:

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ocepaw/1/edit

```
          /*///// Libraries jquery & bootstrap libraries ///////*/

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

```
  /*///// relevant HTML: Targets (pop1,2,3) & Triggers (Previous & Next buttons) ///////*/

        <a  href="#" id="pop1" class="btn" data-content="GREAT CONTENT3" data-original-title="Gamification 1/3">
        </a>

        <a  href="#" id="pop2" class="btn" data-content="GREAT CONTENT3" data-original-title="Gamification 3/3">
        </a>


        <a href="#" id="pop3" class="btn" data-content="GREAT CONTENT3" data-original-title="Gamification 3/3">
        </a>


<a href="#" id="NextBtn" class="btn btn-primary"> NEXT </a>

<a href="#" id="PreviousBtn" class="btn btn-primary"> PREVIOUS </a>



    /*///// CSS ///////*/

      var currentPopover = -1;
      var popovers = [];

     // Initialize all the popovers to be "manually" displayed.
   popovers.push($("#pop1").popover({ trigger: 'manual' }));
   popovers.push($("#pop2").popover({ trigger: 'manual' }));
   popovers.push($("#pop3").popover({ trigger: 'manual' }));


    // On each button click, hide the //currently displayed popover
    // and show the next one.



    $("#NextBtn").click(function() {
    if (currentPopover >= 0) {
    popovers[currentPopover].popover('hide');
    }

    currentPopover = currentPopover + 1;
    popovers[currentPopover].popover('show');


    });


    $("#PreviousBtn").click(function() {

    popovers[currentPopover].popover('hide');


    currentPopover = currentPopover  -1;
    popovers[currentPopover].popover('show');


    });
```

Comment: Last script is missing " from the end of the url and if you have a working jsbin you might as well post that too.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ocepaw/1/edit

Comment: What errors are you getting in the debug console?

Comment: Strangely enough, none!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a long time ago. Here's how i solved it: i changed the order of my imported .css and .js files. Try to load first bootstrap's required files and then everything else. Hopefully it will work for you too! if not then there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: How about declaring 

`http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js`

just before </body> tag

Comment: bootstrap-popover.js is not needed since already included on bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the CSS and JS with no redundancies and in correct order:

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```